# eclipse + m2e + junit + infinitest + eclemma?

Tags: eclipse, m2e, eclemma, infinitest

I have Eclipse for Java Developer 4.3 with m2e, eclemma, infinitest. My project uses Eclipse m2e with junit 4.11.

My intention is to have coverage info updated every time infinitest re-runs the tests affected by last save. Is it possible?

At the moment I'm able to manually run a test with Coverage and see code highlighted, but when I change code infinitest kicks in and coverage highlight disappears.

Answer (score 1):

I created a run configuration for JUnit, which aggregates all tests in a specific scope - `java/test/src` in my case - and executes them.

I call it from time to time to update the coverage information. Depending on how many test cases or suits you have, what you intend may slow down your working process.

Alternatively you could add some kind of hook to every test case you write. If `infinitest` detects changes and executes a test, every other gets called too. But I wouldn't recommend that.